# Як перекласти COUNTRY SUPPLY AGREEMENT?

Tags: переклад, from-english, документація

Потрібно перекласти COUNTRY SUPPLY AGREEMENT.

Щодо "SUPPLY AGREEMENT", то тут, наче. однозначно,   - договір поставки.
Такий переклад дає багато джерел, зокрема [це](http://www.m-translate.com.ua/perekladach/english/en-uk#text=SUPPLY%20AGREEMENT&direction=en-uk)  і таке визначення містить [Цивільний кодекс України](http://yurist-online.com/ukr/uslugi/yuristam/kodeks/003/712.php).

А от щодо "COUNTRY" виникають сумніви. 
Оскільки вжити слово "державний" надало б цьому договору статусу прийнятого на державному рівні, так писати не можна.

*То як правильно перекласти COUNTRY SUPPLY AGREEMENT?*

Comment: А про що (неюридичною мовою) угода взагалі? Вона ж не про "поставку країни", і не про поставку сільської місцевості.

Comment: Дві масштабні материнські компанії мають вже укладену угоду про надання послуг, ця ж стосується надання послуг дочірніми компаніями (або філіями чи представництвами) всередині конкретної країни.
Тобто на локальному рівні (всередині держави) надання послуг.

Comment: ну дослівний переклад тут непотрібен (це як юрист і практик кажу). Достатньо буде написати в українському тексті "Угода про постачання в межах країни" або аналогічно. Українські юридичні традиції це цілком допускають, а кращого перекладу лінгвістичного все одно не вийде. Фраза "угода про внутрішньокраїнне постачання" звучить жахливо.

Comment: Дуже Вам дякую!

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'AlliedBits добрий день. Ваш коментар - це майже відповідь на питання. Якби ви послались на кілька джерел і докладно пояснили свою позицію, з нього можна було б зробити повноцінну відповідь. Напіввідповіді у коментарях на цьому сайті не заохочуються, тож  допрацюйте й опублікуйте як питання, будь ласка.